# How does this multiple void pointers function work?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have an example code about thread creation in C. In the part where I create the thread, I don't get what all the void pointers are for, and what do they do.

```
void* pthread_function(int thread_id) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("I'm thread number %d in mutual exclusión\n",thread_id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    // Init mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    // Create threads
    pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
    long int i;
    for (i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;++i) {
        pthread_create(thread+i,NULL,(void* (*)(void*))pthread_function (void*)(i));
    }

}
```

How do the pointers work here?

```
pthread_create(thread+i,NULL,(void* (*)(void*))pthread_function (void*)(i));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you notice that the function which  is supposed to return a pointer to void does not have a return statement? I recommend ignoring this kind of code and look elsewhere.

Comment: Focus on the cast `(void* (*)(void*))` and what is being cast `pthread_function` and the type of argument it takes (and how that differs from the original cast), and what final cast is made to make it work. Compare that to the prototype for `pthread_create` in the man page.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think the first **(void* )** this is common in pthread_create from the man page. The second **( * )** I guess is a pointer to pthread_function. The third **(void*))** Is the one I don't truly understand.

Comment: This code won't even compile, and is generally poorly written for several reasons. Just find a better example as @Yunnosch wrote.

Comment: Ok, I guess I shouldn't waste my time with it then. I will look for other examples. Though I would still like to understand what the intention behind `(void* (*)(void*))` is.

Comment: @Yunnosch: First, the function calls `pthread_exit` on its only control path, so it never returns without supplying a return value. Second, the C standard does not require a function with a non-void declared return type to return a value. It is not uncommon in generic programming (which, in C, requires using `void *`, as in `qsort`) to provide for things that may or may not be used by clients…

Comment: … Unlike the number of function arguments, which I expect the standard required to match because some architectures are unable to readily handle mismatched arguments counts, handling a missing return value does not pose an implementation problem. The standard does not define the behavior if the return value is used, but, since pthreads is an implementation-dependent extension to the language, the implementation is free to permit and define this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread function is supposed to have the following signature:

```
void *thread_func(void *thread_param);
```

If you have such a function, you can create a thread with it without such a casting mess:

```
void *thread_func(void *thread_param)
{
  printf("Success!\n");
  return NULL;
}

...
pthread_t thread_var;
int param = 42;
int result = pthread_create(&thread_var, NULL, thread_func, &param);
```

Unfortunately the thread function in your example does not have the proper signature. 
Therefore the authore decided not to fix it, but to mess around with weird casts.

The type of the function is `(void*(*)(void*))`. The author tries to make wrong ends meet with casting the thread function:

```
(void* (*)(void*))pthread_function
```

But then another error is introduced: Not the function address is cast but the function is called and the return value is used for the cast:

```
pthread_function (void*)(i)
```

This does not even compile as it is a syntax error. It should probably be

```
pthread_function((void*)i)
```

Or it could be meant to be like this:

```
pthread_create(thread+i,NULL,(void* (*)(void*))pthread_function, (void*)(i));
```

But as this is all wrong anyway, it doesn't really matter.

You better search again for a correct example for thread creation.

Comment: Thanks. I don't fully understand it, but I can see where the logic lies. I don't know why my teacher thought this was a good example...